# Finding the recursive formula for the sum XOR value zero problem with values 0 to 5 (both inclusive),

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic-programming

**Problem Statement:** We have an integer N. We have to determine the number of arrays of length N such that it satisfies the following conditions:

- Each value of the array is between 0 to 5, inclusively
- XOR sum of all value of the array is zero

Constraints:

```
1 <= T <= 5
1 <= N <= 10^5
```

Example solutions are 1, 6, and 28 for N equals 1, 2, and 3 respectively.

I know that this a dynamic programming problem and it require a DP state of [index][XOR], where the index is the number of elements already set, XOR is the total XOR of all these elements, and at DP[index][XOR] we will store the number of arrays fulfilling this condition; the final answer will be found at dp[N][0].

**The problem is I am not able to write a recursive solution to this problem. By recursive solution, I mean piecewise formula for getting a generalized solution for any value of N.** Writing a recursive formula would be sufficient, I would then be able to write it's DP version. Can you help with that? Here is my current code:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

int main(){
  int n;
  cin >> n;
  int dp[n+1][n+1];
  memset(dp, 0, sizeof(dp));
  dp[0][0] = 1; // For index = 1, and XOR = 1, the answer is 1.

  for(i = 1; i <= n; i++){
      for(j = 0; j < n; j++) {
          // dp[i][j] = ?
          // Having trouble in transmitting values to higher values of i's and j's.
          // How to update the value of dp array?
      }
  }
  cout << (dp[N][1]);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `int dp[n+1][n+1];` is invalid C++, as it uses VLA extension.

Comment: forgot to type int there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved the DP construction using the elementary method.

Answer (score 1):

You don't necessarily need duplicates in the array to make the XOR zero, for example A = [1, 2, 3]. This seems to be a simple exercise in dynamic programming, where you have a dp state of [index][XOR], where index is the number of elements already set, XOR is the total XOR of all these elements, and at dp[index][XOR] you store the number of arrays fulfilling this condition; the final answer will be found at dp[N][0].

Comment: If you have x ways to make an array of length i-1 with a total XOR of 4, for example, you'll have found x more ways to make an array of length i with an XOR of 4 (if you set the i'th entry to 0). This is the basic idea behind the transition. Also note that dp should not be n by n: only the first dimension has to be n, the second should just be the number of possible XORs, which is 8 (maxes out at 4 ^ 2 ^ 1 = 7), and you should output dp[N][0] at the end.

Comment: Write your apprach in two or three lines in a separate answer and I will mark it as accepted. @Jarod42

Comment: @Jarod42 The question has reopened, so you sure can.

Answer (score 1):

With dynamic programming, you might compute number of way to have any result.
with xor number from 0 to 5 (`0b1001`), max value is 7 (`0b1111`)

```
// Compute the number of ways to have target with extra number 0-5
// knowing the number of ways to obtain any number from 0-7
std::size_t sum(const std::array<std::size_t, 8>& last, std::size_t target)
{
    std::size_t res = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i <= 5; ++i) {
        res += last[i ^ target]; // i^target ^ i == target
    }
    return res;
}
```

- Initial values for 0 numbers is `{1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}`. (degenerated case?)
- Initial values for 1 numbers is `{1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0}` (which can be obtained from above).

And so

```
    constexpr std::size_t n = 10; // The one we compute.
    // xor numbers <= 5 (0b1001) can go up to 7 (0b1111)
    std::array<std::size_t, 8> dp{{1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}};
    // dp[i] represent number of way to reach a total xor of i

    // We might use vector to keep history,
    // but for computation, only last result is sufficient.

    for (int i = 0; i != n; ++i) {
        dp = {
            sum(dp, 0),
            sum(dp, 1),
            sum(dp, 2),
            sum(dp, 3),
            sum(dp, 4),
            sum(dp, 5),
            sum(dp, 6),
            sum(dp, 7)};
    }
    std::cout << dp[0] << std::endl;
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/52pbJO)

Comment: Thank you for the ans.